# knockoutjs not updating

Tags: knockout.js

I must have missed something in this example. Could anyone let me know what might be wrong?

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/EBxy4/42/

screen: [shared screen](http://jsfiddle.net/EBxy4/42/embedded/result/)

When you update the value in box 1 in row 1, the value in lower corner doesn't change.

The code is:

```
function revenueStream(w1, w2, w3) {
    var self = this;
    self.week1Amount = ko.observable(w1);
    self.week2Amount = ko.observable(w2);
    self.week3Amount = ko.observable(w3);
}

function revenueStreamCategory(revenueStreams) {
    var self = this;
    self.revenueStreams = ko.observalrevenueStreams;

    self.week1Sum = ko.computed(function () {
        var sum = 0.0;

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.revenueStreams, function(item) {
            sum += item.week1Amount();
        });      
        return sum;
    });    
}

var rs = [];
rs.push(new revenueStream(10, 11, 12));
rs.push(new revenueStream(13, 14, 15));    
rs.push(new revenueStream(16, 17, 18));

var vm = new revenueStreamCategory(rs);      

ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("test"));​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your binding, replace this:

```
<td><input data-bind="value: week1Amount()" /></td>
```

with:

```
<td><input data-bind="value: week1Amount" /></td>
```

Here's a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/EBxy4/44/

I even fixed your subtotal which was concatenating rather than summing!

Comment: @user1919252: You're asking two questions in one, but I came up with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EBxy4/63/). When you make an observableArray, it's only observing adding or removing items from the array. It doesn't automatically make anything you put in the array observable, so I wrapped your data in another class. If declaring all the data as `revenueData` gets too verbose for you, you can always add code to your `revenueStream` class to automatically convert the array of numbers for you.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I apologize asked two questions here. Just want to see if someone here knowing a way to solve my puzzle. I agree with you about the observable array. Using an array may make it more extendable, and easier to initialize. Considering if we need to expand to 13 weeks, the benefit of not hard coding week1Amount, week2Amount, is obvious.